# I have a problem pip installing the dlib library

Tags: pip, face-recognition, dlib

While attempting to pip install dlib, I get the following error:

> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\Users\MUHAMMAD USMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\tools\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD USMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD USMAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\MUHAMMAD USMAN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
> Failed to build dlib
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I would like help understanding the issue with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like [THIS ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10/)
This installation needs some preconditions, so, generally:

1. Install CMake
2. Install visual studio
3. Install cmake module
4. Install dlib library.