# issue in installing dlib library for face recognitions

Tags: python, cmake, face-recognition

I have a problem pip installing the dlib library
While attempting to pip install dlib, I get the following error:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD USMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD USMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD USMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\MUHAMMAD USMAN\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8lhbgb6j\\dlib_38bf52dcd86d47d4bfa0708f58a51173\\build\\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I would like help understanding the issue with the installation

Comment: You already asked the same a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861777/i-have-a-problem-pip-installing-the-dlib-library

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://dlib.net/compile.html) says:

> Either run `pip install dlib --verbose` or grab the latest sources from github, go to the base folder of the dlib repository, and run `python setup.py install`. Once either of these commands finishes running you are ready to use dlib from Python.

**Note that you need to have CMake and a working C++ compiler installed for this to work.**

See [Using dlib from Python](http://dlib.net/compile.html#:%7E:text=Using%20dlib%20from%20Python) for more.